# rm -rf .git removed all my folders including the parent folder?

Tags: bash, git, rm

I ran `rm -rf .git` because I wanted to delete the .git folder for this one small test project. and then do a git init again. See the attached screenshot with my command history.

Today I realized my entire src folder (the parent folder for all my projects) is completely missing.

I believe that I ran the command correctly or worst case scenario I ran it directly into the src (parent folder for all my projects), however, I cannot understand why the src folder is also missing.

I have already looked into other questions on SO, but none of them answers this question:
When running `rm -rf .git` does it look for all folders that have .git and deletes them including the parent folder (src in my case)?

Folder structure:

~/src -> parent folder for all my projects

~/src/vscode/folderName -> many git projects with folderName containing .git

~/src/jmeter/testProject/.git -> what I was trying to delete

[image: bash history]

Comment: Welcome. With only the command history, it's difficult to know what has happened and why. If you could explain the directory structure, and in which directory you ran the command (edit in your post), things would be more clear. However, it's completely certain that `rm -rf .git` does not remove any parent folders. In any case, it seems you need to restore your `src` folder from a recent backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The command `rm -rf .git` would in your current directory delete the subfolder `.git` and all its contents.

The command would not remove other subfolders than `.git`, nor would it remove any parent folders. These are just facts.

In any case, this doesn't explain why another folder on your system is gone. You're probably the only one who can know. I would advice to restore a backup.

Comment: You are correct. The command I ran was right and did exactly what it should do.
I discovered that my issue is coming from somewhere else.